# Retrieve users list from Google Apps after OAuth login

Tags: google-oauth

Is it possible to use OAuth and a Feed to retrieve Google Apps users list from third party application?
I have working script which uses Webmaster feed to retrieve all sites.
There is some information here, but still no success:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Simply with oAuth the Scope should be:

https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/

Then the API call should retrieve users from this feed:

https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/%domain%/user/2.0

Here you can test it:

https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/

Using Google Provisioning API.

Comment: Make sure that you use OAuth2 instead of OAuth because the latter has been deprecated by Google.